# Which JavaScript framework is easier for a newbie: Ember.js, Canjs, Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, angularjs

I'm a newbie web developer, coming from embedded software. C language is like my native language.
I'm trying a MVC framework to write an app that run in a browser for learning purposes.

Would you give me an advice on which JS framework should be easier to get start: emberjs, canjs or Angularjs.

Thank you so much!

Comment: The first thing to do is come up with a project to work on. Once you've got that, any framework will do the job for you. Learning another after getting comfortable with one is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alex, I already have a project to work on.. I also complete reading some book like: Head first Jquery, javascript the good part.. scanning over the 3 framework I feel Angularjs pretty easier than the other 2. I may follow angularjs but not so sure

Comment: Just try them! Read a tutorial on each of them, scan the documentation and make your choice.

Comment: Now I'm about to commit to Angularjs.. because I think it's easier.. Just wanna ask for some advice from professional guys here.. :)

Comment: I think angular is the easiest to understand, the canJS and finally Ember is the most abstracted. I personally like CanJS better.

Comment: Try can.js you won't be disappointed - its not easy to grasp at once, but it's worth to try. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdT4Oq6ZQ68&feature=g-upl

Answer (score 0):

Just look at some popular javascripts frameworks like : jquery,MooTools and YUI.. I think will help you to understand

Comment: I have already familiar and comfortable with jquery.. I think it's time for a framework, and I intend to write a more complicated app.. more than just todo apps.. for learning purpose

Comment: javascript is just a scripting language for front-end interactions. you must look at server-side scripting languages like java and php.JSF is a MVC framework for java and code igniter for PHP.

Comment: I think Python/Django or nodejs/Meteor is my next todo list User1407847  :)

Comment: Ja! Python is fast It will be a good Language to learn, that why Google use it for YOUTUBE and GOOGLE-DRIVE :)